# Computing conditional expectation without integrals or monte carlo sampling

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, truncated-normal-distribution

I have gaussian random variables $(Z,Z_k)\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ and $u\sim\text{Uniform}[0,1]$. Given that
\begin{align*}
y=(1-\boldsymbol{1}\{Z>C\})\boldsymbol{1}\{u<\rho\}+\boldsymbol{1}\{Z>C\}\boldsymbol{1}\{u\geq\rho\}
\end{align*}
where $\boldsymbol{1}\{\cdot\}$ is the indicator function, and $C$ and $\rho$ are fixed constants (i.e., not random variables).

Is it possible to compute $\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k,y]$ without using any integrations (i.e., I want to be able to compute this quickly)? I was thinking this might be possible with the use of some truncated Gaussian property (something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4669171/computing-expectation-of-truncated-conditional-gaussian-r-v)?) or something..? Otherwise, can I compute $\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k,y]$ with just one integral? Thanks.

Comment: The question can be simplified into $Z|Z_k\sim N(0,1)$, $X=\mathbf 1\{Z<C\}\sim B(\Phi(C))$ and $V=\mathbf 1\{U>\rho\}\sim B(\rho)$.